# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint (Parent record exists already)

Tags: sql, asp.net, foreign-key-relationship

I'm getting the error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...." I have searched for similar problems but I cannot find the one that solves mine. Solution I've seen is that I dont have a record on the referenced table. (I have) but still does not work.

I have table called `Parent` and `ParentFeedback` which is referencing the `Parent` table.

I have already created 2 records in `Parent`. Now when I try to insert a `ParentFeedback` record using my Insert statement

```
Insert into ParentFeedback 
Values(@parentid, @feed, @date , @status)
```

I get an error (shown in the title).

I have made sure already that the parentid that I'm putting exists and I am able to grab it and put it in `@parentid`.

But why am I still getting that error?

If you want to see it, [Click here to be directed to the page.](http://hyperdisc.unitec.ac.nz/project11/AddFeedback.aspx)

just search for asdasd firstname and asdasd lastname then put a feedback and submit. asdasd is an existing record in Parent table with ID of 1. which I put for the parentid in my insert.

Comment: Well, the record you are referencing *does not* exist. Either the insert failed without you noticing or you are passing the wrong it. This error message is reliable.

Comment: right you mean unreliable?. in ASP.Net I am passing the date as a string but in MSSQL the date column is in date data type. I think that is causing the problem? Please advise.

Comment: The message is reliable. It is caused exactly by what it says. The parent record does not exist. Not sure what you mean regarding that date column.

Comment: By the way if you followed my message above searching for asdasd will confirm that the record exists it will even show the ID of the asdasd record in Parent table. the ID will then be passed to the method and it will be used on that Insert statement.

Comment: Also another weird thing is that , I add a ParentFeedback record in MSSQL and its perfectly fine, but the same insert statement put into ASP.NET gives me the error. wth?

Comment: Sounds like your asp is not passing all the values correctly, I would try echoing out your query from asp and then try and copy paste that into sql to see if there are any errors. Date Time variables can sometimes cause troubles if not handled correctly.

Comment: Yes I have a big feeling that it is the date time that is causing trouble because im passing it as string and its date data type in sqlserver

Comment: I am inserting my date time as "2014-06-23". already in a format for date date type in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys im really sorry to bother you, I thought that I was passing my parent ID properly but it turns out it aint giving me an ID and its always 0.